# Boost Serialization Problem

Tags: c++, boost, boost-serialization

I'm trying to get two arrays inside my class to use the boost serialization library. I can save the data just fine, but for some reason, I can't load it back. I think it's with ia >> *this; but I have no idea how to fix it. Anyone can point me into the right track?

```
class foo
{

private:
int tileType[512];
int tileSubType[512];

friend std::ostream & operator<<(std::ostream &os, const foo &gp);
friend class boost::serialization::access;
template<class Archive>
void serialize(Archive & ar, const unsigned int version)
{
    ar & tileType;
    ar & tileSubType;
}

public:
foo();

void loadType(string data)
{
    std::stringstream is(data);

    boost::archive::text_iarchive ia(is);
    ia >> *this;
}

string saveType()
{
    stringstream ss(stringstream::in | stringstream::out);
    boost::archive::text_oarchive oa(ss); 
    oa << this;

    return ss.str().c_str();
}

};
```

Comment: compile failure? runtime failure? What is your question?

Answer (score 1):

have you tried

```
 oa << *this;
```

?

You are saving the pointer but loading into the reference, I guess that's not what you want, right?

Answer (score 0):

I ran into some problems trying to use the `>>` and `<<` operators with the archives. Try using the `&` operator for both cases and see if that fixes it for you.